# What does pending approval mean?

Tags: phrase-requests

I have submitted my profile online to the company for consideration of deal with me on my ideas and the company has mentioned online that  my profile is pending approval; what does pending approval mean for my profile?

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of *pending* in a dictionary? Its etymology is also relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to automatically generate a profile (or add any content) on someone else's website will depend on controls that they have in place.

Some companies don't care about or monitor what goes onto their sites and leave it to the user to generate, and the computer system to upload them instantly and automatically.

However, in this case, the company obviously likes to maintain control over what goes onto their site, and so the system is set to require a manual (human) intervention before any profile is uploaded.

Yours is pending (waiting for that human intervention) approval.

HTH